# Nested RecyclerView not getting focus

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` that contains a bunch of `CardViews`. Each `CardView` then has its own `RecyclerView` in it. The problem is that only the "main" `RecyclerView` is scrolling. The nested one in the `CardView` is not getting focus, so I can't scroll it. How can i make it so that both will be scrollable?

**Parent Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout_main"
                                             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_savedFiles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Parent Adapter**

```
public class AdapterSavedFilesCards extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSavedFilesCards.ViewHolderSavedFilesCard>{

/**
 * List of cards in the recycler view
 */
private final ArrayList<CardViewSavedFiles> cards;

private final Context context;

public AdapterSavedFilesCards(final Context context){
    this.context = context;

    cards = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new CardViewSavedFiles[]{
            new CardViewSavedFiles("Card One"),
            new CardViewSavedFiles("Card Two"),
            new CardViewSavedFiles("Card Three")
    }));
}

@Override
public ViewHolderSavedFilesCard onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_saved_files, parent, false);
    return new AdapterSavedFilesCards.ViewHolderSavedFilesCard(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderSavedFilesCard holder, int position){

    //Get the card at this position
    final CardViewSavedFiles card = cards.get(position);

    holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    holder.recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
    holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(card.getAdapterSavedFiles());

    holder.title.setText(card.getTitle());
    holder.subTitle.setText("Subtitle");
    ((CardView)holder.itemView).setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.getContext(), card.getBackgroundColor()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return cards.size();
}

public ArrayList<CardViewSavedFiles> getCards(){
    return cards;
}

protected class ViewHolderSavedFilesCard extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private final TextView title;
    private final TextView subTitle;
    private final RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public ViewHolderSavedFilesCard(final View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        subTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    }
}
}
```

**Child Layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cardView_savedFactors"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/content_padding_start"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/content_padding_end"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Child Adapter**

```
public class AdapterSavedFiles extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSavedFiles.ViewHolderSavedFiles>{

private final ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

private final FILE_TYPE fileType;

public AdapterSavedFiles(final Context context, final FILE_TYPE fileType){
    this.fileType = fileType;

    switch (fileType){
        case ONE:
            files.addAll(Arrays.asList(FileManager.getInstance(context).getFilesDirOne().listFiles()));
            break;
        case TWO:
            files.addAll(Arrays.asList(FileManager.getInstance(context).getFilesDirTwo().listFiles()));
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolderSavedFiles onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_saved_file, parent, false);
    return new AdapterSavedFiles.ViewHolderSavedFiles(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderSavedFiles holder, int position){

    holder.fileName.setText("List item " + position);

    switch (fileType){

        case ONE:
            holder.icon.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.getContext(), R.color.primary)));
            holder.icon.setText("P");
            break;

        case TWO:
            holder.icon.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.getContext(), R.color.green)));
            holder.icon.setText("F");
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return files.size();
}

public ArrayList<File> getFiles(){
    return files;
}

protected class ViewHolderSavedFiles extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private final TextView fileName;
    private final TextView icon;

    public ViewHolderSavedFiles(final View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        icon = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        fileName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
    }
}
}
```

**Layout Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use ListView in Child adapter in onBindViewHolder instead of TextView.This may solve scrolls child items inside CardView.

Comment: Using a `ListView`, I am able to click on items, but scrolling still does not work.